# how to convert 1 column value into multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose if i have one table "Title" In this table there are 4 columns.

```
Bookid, Isbn, TitleName, Description.

1         123  english     this is a english buk.

2        123  english      Its author is "Mr xyz"
```

Now you see that b'coz of description same book appear 2 times.

Now how can we get the below output.Plese Guide

```
Bookid, Isbn,         TitleName,           Description1,                  Description2

1         123         english              "this is a english buk"         "Its author is Mr xyz"
```

Comment: which database are u using.. sql server or mysql?

Comment: Do you really need , as many number of description , the Description column will generate dynamically as Description1,Description2,Description3,...... like.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you want a dynamic way of producing these results.  You can use Dynamic SQL to generate a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Using dynamic SQL will allow you to have additional descriptions automatically added to your results.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('Description'+cast(row_number() over (partition by bookid, isbn, titlename order by bookid) as varchar(10))) 
                    from title
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
      = 'SELECT bookid, isbn, titlename,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select bookid, isbn, titlename, description,
              ''Description''+ cast(row_number() over (partition by bookid, isbn, titlename order by bookid) as varchar(10)) rn
            from title
         ) x
         pivot 
         (
            min(description)
            for rn in(' + @cols + ')
         ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cce81/7).

As you add new descriptions for the books, a new column will be added to the results when you execute the query.

Comment: @VANDANAPANDEY what do you mean it is not working? Do you get an error message? Did you review the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cce81/7) it shows a working example?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery to calculate the minimum and maximum `BookId` per book.  Then you can join the two descriptions:

```
select  min(BookId)
,       Isdn
,       TitleName
,       max(case when rn = 1 then Description end) as Descr1
,       max(case when rn = 2 then Description end) as Descr2
,       max(case when rn = 3 then Description end) as Descr3
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by Isdn, TitleName order by BookId) as rn
        ,       BookId
        ,       Isdn
        ,       TitleName
        ,       Description 
        from    Title
        ) as ids
group by
        Isdn
,       TitleName
```

Comment: but if have one more columns like bookid 3 with some different values. So, in that case can this code will work. Or can we use cursor for that.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, you can use `row_number()` to assist with pivoting.  The edited answer works for up to 3 descriptions but can easily be expanded.

Comment: When there are more than 3 description then , what to do ?

Comment: @JDeveloper: Just add a new column like `max(case when rn = 4 then Description end) as Descr4`

Comment: Yes mate, that's right. But , adding a new column in query is static  approach. But , how to know how many column I should add?

Comment: ya dats rt... if 1 book have 3 description and another book have 5 description. Then every time i have to use case.

Comment: @Andomar thnx this code works. Bt i guess this is not the permanent solution. Can we make this code dynamic. So that every time when some new description add with the book, our column also add.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 select * 
 from
 (
      select 
           *,
           row_number() over (partition by bookid, isbn, titlename order by description) rn
      from yourtable
 ) src
 pivot
 ( max(description) for rn in ([1],[2],[3])) p
```

Answer (score 0):

@bluefeet, I modified your query to allow more than 10 descriptions (sorted)....

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((select c from (SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME('Description'+cast(row_number() over (partition by bookid, isbn, titlename order by bookid) as varchar(11))) AS C
                    from title) TBL group by c order by CAST(Replace(REPLACE(C,',[Description',''),']','') as int)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
      = 'SELECT bookid, isbn, titlename,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select bookid, isbn, titlename, description,
              ''Description''+ cast(row_number() over (partition by bookid, isbn, titlename order by bookid) as varchar(10)) rn
            from title
         ) x
         pivot 
         (
            min(description)
            for rn in(' + @cols + ')
         ) p '

execute(@query)
```